# MonoTouch - missing header files when editing xib

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xib

I am on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.0 with Xcode 4.2 for IOS 5 and Xamarin's MonoTouch.

("Cross platform mobile development tools that allow you to use C# and .NET to create apps for iOS and Android") and on VMWare 8.0.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I am testing MonoTouch and when I follow this [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/hello_iphone) then at one step, I have to do my xib file with xcode Interface Builder I have no header files.
Whereas these `AppDelegate.h` and `HelloWorld_iPhoneController.h` are needed.

Do I have to write these ? or there is no any problems ?

Thanks and sorry for my English, I am French.

Comment: Xamarin is the company - MonoTouch is the product/framework you're using.  I corrected your tags to include MonoTouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed all the steps then MonoDevelop should have created the **xib** file.

> When you open a Xib in Xcode from MD, Xcode opens...

You just have to double-click on the **xib** file (in MonoDevelop's solution pane) to open Xcode.

You can then continue the tutorial from the Xcode's Interface Builder.

p.s. you can contact support@xamarin.com and ask your question in french.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect I just change the name of my project. Thanks a lot. Before it was HelloWorld and now it s HelloWorld_iPhone. That all

Comment: This didnt work for me. I do not have a h-file, so when clicking the Assistant Editor, I just get "No Assistant Results". I tried to manually create the h-file, but that didnt make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was ok but in Xcode I haven' t header files even if I can do what I want in Xcode. I conclude that I have to do the header files Delegate.h and HelloWorld_iPhoneController.h by myself. Thanks

Comment: I created one h-file myself (the HelloWorldViewController.h) but it did help.