# Missing h-files and Assistant Editor not working because of it (monoTouch/MonoDevelop)

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am missing the .h-files when I just started my HelloWorld in MonoTouch/MonoDevelop. I have the [same question as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839333/monotouch-missing-header-files-when-editing-xib), but the answer provided did not help me.

I just installed everything needed for MonoTouch on a MacBook running Lion.
I followed the steps/instructions to install (see [here](http://blong.com/Articles/CSharpMonoTouch5/MonoTouch.htm#Gettingstarted)) and then created a new solution.

But since there are no .h-files, this means that whem I use the interface Builder in Xcode, I only get the "No Assistant Result" when I open the "Assistant Builder".

I have tried to create the HelloWorlsViewController.h file manually, but it doesnt seem to help either.

**EDIT**
Here is a screencast on DailyMotion that shows the problem:
http://www.dailymotion.com/waggerdagger#videoId=xok9gs

Comment: Hi Ted, I am experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I closed monoDevelop and reopened it and its working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Try Closing down XCode and MonoDevelop completely and then reopen MonoDevelop. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

How are you opening the xib file in Xcode?

You need to double-click the xib file ***from within MonoDevelop*** so that MonoDevelop creates a fake project (with header files) for Xcode to use.

Comment: I am opening it from MonoDevelop, double-click as well as right-click --> Open with --> Xcode Interface Builder. No h-file is created. Furthermore, if I create my own h-file, the "highlighting" in the h-file doesn't seem to "work", ie it doesn't recognise the syntax etc...

Comment: I dunno, I can't reproduce this. It works perfectly fine here... Can you make a screencast?

Comment: Im usually a Windows-user, but I'll try to find a way to do a screencast on the Mac, and post it when I do =)

Comment: Here it is:
http://www.dailymotion.com/waggerdagger#videoId=xok9gs
Note that I am using a slow computer, so when its loading its wise to jump a little bit =)

Comment: Looks like Xcode is still indexing the TestApp project files when you started editing. Try waiting until that progress bar is done (it suggests there are 5 files, that would suggest the .h files *are* there, they just weren't processed yet)

Comment: So if I create a new project and double-click the .xib as quickly as I can and then click the Assistant editor toolbar button in Xcode, I get a blank gray screen as well until the "Indexing project files" in Xcode is done, then the .h file loads in the second editor pane.

Comment: Actually, there are no h-files. You can see that in the video - you see no files of type .h anywhere in the solution browser etc. And it doesnt help waiting. In the video I show you a solution from scratch, but it doesnt matter if I take an "old one" (my first HelloWorld for example). Same thing...

Comment: ... and I take that back. Now it seems to work. The weird thing is that the previous solution didnt work, and I sat at the computer trying for an hour to no avail...

Comment: Uh... you gotta expand the tree in the left-hand side. They are there. Trust me.

Comment: I guess you can add as an answer, and I'll put it down as an answer. i will try it a few times more though... and when thats done, onwards with the tutorials =)

Answer (score 0):

Problem for me was that I had moved Xcode out of Application folder to another folder. Moving it back fixed it for me.