# Header file for view controller not created with MonoTouch

Tags: xcode, header, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

This question is the same as this [Missing h-files and Assistant Editor not working because of it (monoTouch/MonoDevelop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240984/missing-h-files-and-assistant-editor-not-working-because-of-it-monotouch-monode) but none of the answers work for me.  When I double-click the XIB file from monodevelop no header file is created in XCode 4.2, even after I edit the XIB in Xcode and re-save, or when I quit Xcode and monodevelop and re-open.  I have expanded every folder in Xcode and there is no ViewController.h file anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen quite a few times :( The solution is to manually create the partial class in MonoDevelop, inherit from the UI class you need, and finally add the Register attribute.

```
[Register("MyCustomView")]
public partial class MyCustomView : UIViewController {
    ....
}
```

Once you do that, and save your code in MonoDevelop it should automatically rebuild the xcode project file for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and as of 5 minutes ago it seems to have resolved itself. I don't know what the direct reasoning for this was, but it started after I closed xcode, monodevelop and restarted my mac. It didn't work the first time I rebooted, but I noticed that there was another xcode project open when I double-clicked on the xib in monodevelop. So I closed the project and xcode again. Next time I double-clicked on the xib it was there!

So, my guess is it is some kind of fluke or system caching issue. If you haven't been able to resolve it yet maybe try doing a reboot so the system cache can be cleared and make sure you don't have another project open in xcode when you try to open the xib from monodevelop?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that deleting the "*obj*" folder of your project often helps. In there MD is storing all the helper fiels required by Xcode. This folder is not properly cleaned if you "clean" your solution from the build menu.
Quit Xcode, delete the folder, double click your XIB and the folder will be recreated.